# append to an array as a value in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, key-value

i am returning a structure of an object of folders and the contents of the json files contained in them. this is how it's looks like.

```
{
  DailyTask: [ { title: 'Chores', body: 'Wash the roof and sweep the bed' } ],
  monday: [{ title: 'madrid', body: 'Wash the roof and sweep the bed' }  ],
}
```

i have a problem when a folder has more than two files, because i can't find a way to append to the array of either monday or DailyTask

i tried doing concat or push but they wouldn't work at first because the object property is undefined so i did the first assignment would be done via square brackets and subsequent ones will be done via push or unshift i.e x is the json file

```
if (sum[key] == undefined) {
            sum[key] = x;
        } else {
            sum[key].unshift(x);
        }
```

gives me this

```
{
  DailyTask: [ { title: 'Chores', body: 'Wash the roof and sweep the bed' } ],
  monday: [
    [ [Object] ],
    { title: 'madrid', body: 'Wash the roof and sweep the bed' }
  ]
}
```

it shows as [[Object]], how do i make the actual contents of the object show.

Comment: Ciao, so you want create a unique array that contains both objects `{ title: 'Chores', body: 'Wash the roof and sweep the bed' }` and `{ title: 'madrid', body: 'Wash the roof and sweep the bed' }` correct?

Comment: Show us result of before and after.

Comment: @Sascha the first code block and the last code block are the results

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito i want to add more of the format { title: 'XXXXX', body: 'Do something xxxxxxx' }

Comment: yourObject.monday.push({title:"foo"}); should work. Provide a jsfiddle of your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the logic you are presenting `x` equals `[ {...} ]`. that is why it works for

```
sum[key] = x;
// outputs:
// title: [ { ... } ]
```

But fails on the other: `title: [ [{...}], {...} ]`

try this:

```js
if (sum[key] == undefined) {
  sum[key] = [x[0]] ; // or simply leave it x;
} else {
  sum[key].unshift(x[0]);
}
```

Comment: you misunderstood me, i am pushing an object of format { title: 'XXX', body: 'bla bla bla bla' } not title: [ [{...}], {...} ]

Comment: but that's exactly the output you are getting. `[[ [Object] ],{ title: 'madrid', body: 'Wash the roof and sweep the bed' }]`. my offered solution doesn't work still?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(sum[key]==undefined) sum[key]=[x];
else sum[key].push(x);
```

Comment: this doesn't work , the subsequent pushed objects show as [ [Object] ]

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me.
What is `x`?
`console.log` it and see if it's something like this: `{"title":"something", "body":"something else"}`.